# How does the intercom javascript API track leads?

Tags: javascript, php, session, intercom

In the intercom javascript is described that when someone starts talking to you through the messenger they will switch from `Visitor` to `Lead`. That said, when someone has become a lead they should keep their conversation history throughout their session.

Now the problem:

We don't use PHP sessions. And so on a page refresh, their conversation history is gone.

My question:

Are our non existent PHP sessions causing the fact that none of our leads keep their conversation history? If so, is there any workaround or solution to this?

Thanks,

Wouter :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for intercom, a 3rd party service, and not specifically about a programming problem.

Comment: How is this not a programming problem? This could be my fault in implementing the api, which is literally programming..

Comment: I'm confused, because what you describe as "the problem" is the answer to the question you're asking. OTOH, it's trivial for JavaScript to store a Lead ID in LocalStorage and restore the session from there after a page refresh. But you shouldn't have to manually implement this basic feature.

Comment: @ChrisG That's what I think the problem is, but since I don't know that for sure I thought I'd ask the question here. I saw that sitting in LocalStorage, but the conversations object is empty. Same goes for the hasConversations bool